# How can I finish the ceiling in this detached garage?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, roof, garage, lumber

I'd like to finish the ceiling in this detached garage with insulation/drywall. I've attached some pictures but I definitely don't think there are enough (rafters/joists not sure which one?) to support strapping for drywall.

My plan right now is to add a couple more of these similar joists near the front of the garage by the door so that there are enough to support 1x3 strapping. I don't know how to go about doing it because it's a 24ft garage and I'm not sure how I would get wood that long to my house. Is there a way to join smaller pieces together for something like this?

Let me know if this sounds possible or if there's something else I should be doing. I've attached some pictures (please ignore the mess it's a WIP).

Thanks everyone!

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qT5o.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about getting 16' joists, cutting them to 12' and sistering them together with the leftover wood from the cut. See photo below. You could use shorter pieces of lumber and have more joints. This will keep the joist straight for installing the strapping.

[image]

Comment: Interesting might end up going down this route. Is it ok to have more than one sistering on a joist?

Comment: @CameronHoward  Yes.

Comment: You can also help support the new joists by connection them with sturdy steel strap to the ridge. (And I’d suggest 1x4 for the cross-strapping… it allows for a little more screwing surface and slop.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  Love "and slop".  You mean that the joists might not be perfectly straight and exactly on center??  lol.